# Split CRLF between TCP payloads

Tags: http, parsing, tcp, newline

I'm currently writing a low-level HTTP parser and have run into the following issue:

I am receiving HTTP data on a packet-by-packet basis, i.e. TCP payloads one at a time. When parsing this data, I am using the HTTP protocol standards of searching for CRLF to delineate header lines, chunk data (in the case of chunked-encoding), and the dual CRLF to delineate header from body.

My question is: do I need to worry about the possibility of CRLF being split between two TCP packet payloads? For example, the HTTP header will finish with CRLFCRLF. Is it possible that two subsequent TCP packets will have CR, and then LFCRLF?

I am assuming that yes; this is a case to worry about, since the application (HTTP) and TCP layers are rather independent of each other.

Any insight into this would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible that the CRLF gets split into different TCP packets. Just think about the possibility that a single HTTP header is exactly one byte longer than the TCP MTU. In that case, there is only room for the CR, but not for the NL.

So no matter how tricky your code will get, it must be able to handle this case of splitting.

Comment: Absolutely correct; you can get away with making assumptions "most" of the time, but shortcuts will eventually catch up with you.

Answer (score 1):

What language are you working in? Does it not have some form of buffered read functionality for the socket, so you don't have this issue?

The short answer to your question is yes, theoretically you do have to worry about it, because it is possible the packets would arrive like that. It is very unlikely, because most HTTP endpoints will tend to send the header in one packet and the body in subsequent packets. This is less by convention and more by the nature of the way most socket-based programs/languages work.

One thing to bear in mind is that while the protocol standards are quite clear about the CRLF separation, many people who implement HTTP (clients in particular, but to some degree servers as well) don't know/care what they are doing and will not obey the rules. They will tend to separate lines with LF only - particularly the blank line between the head and the body, the number of code segments I have seen with this problem I could not count up to quickly. While this is technically a protocol violation, most servers/clients will accept this behaviour and work around it, so you will need to as well.

If you can't do some kind of buffered read functionality, there is some good news. All you need to do is read a packet at a time into memory and tag the data on to the previous packet(s). Every time you have read a packet, scan your data for a double CRLF sequence, if you don't find it, read the next packet, and so on until you find the end of the head. This will be relatively small memory usage, because the head of any request shouldn't ever be more than 5-6KB, which given an ethernet MTU of (averaging around) 1450 bytes means you shouldn't ever need to load more than 4 or 5 packets into memory to cope with it.